# MySQL cursor stored procedure condition showing duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

From the stored procedure and table duplicate rows are being returned in the result as shown in the screenshot. As in table only one record matching.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The select in the loop doesn’t make sense, what do you intend to get from the table?

Comment: I need ti get where redisstate and atestate have same number in the table.

Comment: Then you don’t need the table or the procedure you can do this with a simple select. Expected output would help clarify

Comment: I used condition in cursor statement and its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used condition in cursor statement and its worked fine.

[image: updated procedure]

[image: Correct result]